# Переименование файлов в каталоге

Tags: c++, linux, файлы

Подскажите почему не происходит замена, компилирует, но замена не происходит.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <sstream>


int main() 
{
std::string directory = "katalog";
int i = 1;
std::string s, oldname, newname;
const char * OLDNAME, * NEWNAME;
DIR *dir;
struct dirent *entry;
const char * DIRECTORY;
DIRECTORY = directory.c_str();
dir = opendir (DIRECTORY);
while ((entry=readdir(dir))!=NULL)
{
    std::stringstream out;
    out << i;
    s = out.str();
    oldname = (std::string(DIRECTORY)+entry->d_name).c_str();
    newname = (std::string(DIRECTORY)+"" + s).c_str();
    OLDNAME = oldname.c_str();
    NEWNAME = newname.c_str();
    rename(OLDNAME, NEWNAME);
    i++;
}   
closedir(dir);
}
```

Comment: Самое главное он видит файлы, проверил через printf("%s\n", entry->d_name); - отобразило содержимое в каталоге. Значит проблема заключается в замене.

Comment: проверьте результат выполнения функции rename и код ошибки в errno

Comment: errno проверил, работает верно.

Comment: По-поводу rename, как его проверить в этом случае?

Comment: Вы наверное думаете, что  введя сложности, лишные ходы и лишные имена, ваш код станет круче? Это не так_ пишите проще...

Comment: Нет, я б с радостью, но я только обучаюсь. Если вы думаете что это весь код мой , то ошибаетесь, я большинство  нашёл в интернете и использовал в своей задачи. Если вы знаете как можно решить на много легче, то я буду очень рад если посоветуете. Только сразу говорю, мне нужно через dirent.h , знаю что есть boost::filesystem,windows.h.Но мне надо этим способом.

Comment: Я использую всю информацию что я знаю и стараюсь использовать подходящую информацию в определенных  таких задачах. Но я практически не обнаружил решения таких задач. И за этого спрашиваю вас.

Comment: @Alex, выведи `OLDNAME` и `NEWNAME` перед переименованием и сразу увидишь, где ошибка...

Comment: Хм, ничего не изменилось.Так же компилирует , но ничего не происходит.

Comment: У с функций необходимо проверять результат и `errno`. `opendir` у вас может возвращать нулевой дескриптор, `rename` может возвращать не ноль в случае неудачи. Соответственно выполните программу построчно, проверяя успешность вызовов функций.

Comment: В чём удивление ошибок никаких не выдаёт. Opendir и errno работают хорошо. Я писал не существующий каталог выводила всё верно. А opendir выводит существующие файлы в  каталоге как и должно быть.

Comment: Сразу предупреждаю, точно не знаю, но мне не нравится идея менять каталог, одновременно читая его. Наверное, стоит сначала прочесть все имена  в память, а потом сделать все rename.

Comment: Не знаю как это можно реализовать, есть вариант  сначала просто открыть сделать проверку на количество файлов и закрыть, а потом открыть сделать переименование. Но это проблему не меняет.

Comment: В коде отсутствует обработка ошибок.

Comment: В смысле ? Не понял тебя.

Comment: ОК, посмотрел код повнимательней.  У вас просто ошибка в формировании имен (как нового, так и старого). Кроме этого не следует пытаться переименовывать элементы `.` и `..` (!!!). Например, для имени `aa` на 3-ей итерации (в первых двух будут как раз `.` и `..`)  будет вызвана `rename ("katalogaa", "katalog3");`. А вы видимо хотели `rename ("katalog/aa", "katalog/3);`? / И все же это не снимает моего подозрения, что одновременно читать и менять каталог (переименовывая файлы в нем) в общем случае нельзя.

Comment: Во, помогите пожалуйста, как не менять имя каталога, а менять содержимое в каталоге? Как правильно это написать?

Comment: Ловите (просто стало интересно, прав ли я с большим каталогом (прав)). Кстати, если хотите, чтобы человек, к которому вы обращаетесь в комментарии увидел это (нотификация), обращайтесь `@nick`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот программа, которая переименовывает (новое имя файла, совпадает с его "порядковым номером") файлы в каталоге.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main () 
{
  const char *directory = "katalog";
  char oldname[PATH_MAX + 1],
    newname[PATH_MAX + 1];
  int pos = sprintf(oldname, "%s/", directory);
  strcpy(newname, oldname);
  char *fromfile = oldname + pos,
    *tofile = newname + pos;

  DIR *dir = opendir(directory);
  if (!dir)
    exit((perror(directory), 1));
  struct dirent *entry;
  int i = 0;

  while ((entry = readdir(dir))) {
    if (strcmp(entry->d_name, ".") == 0 ||
        strcmp(entry->d_name, "..") == 0)
      continue;
    strcpy(fromfile, entry->d_name);
    sprintf(tofile, "%d", ++i);
    if (rename(oldname, newname))
      fprintf(stderr, "Can't rename [%s] to [%s] (%m)\n",
              oldname, newname);
  }

  closedir(dir);
}
```

Тщательно не исследовал, но с каталогом в котором 500 файлов она работает правильно, а вот если в каталоге 50000 файлов, то в результате в нем остается те же 50000 файлов, но присутствуют файлы с именами 60000, 69999 и т.п. (более 50000), которых быть не должно. Такой результат означает лишь то, что в ходе переименований имена некоторых, уже переименованных файлов, читаются снова.

Т.о. корректная программа для подобного массового переименования должна сначала прочесть все имена в каталоге (в память или временный файл), выполнить `closedir()` (в принципе, это не обязательно, главное не читать содержимое `DIR *dir` снова) и затем, перебирая запомненные имена в цикле, переименовать их.

Comment: Всё работает,  спасибо, но вопрос, а нельзя никак формат файла сохранять?

Comment: + Объясните пожалуйста что делает PATH_MAX

Comment: `grep -R '^#define  *PATH_MAX' /usr/include/  ...  /usr/include/linux/limits.h:#define PATH_MAX        4096 /* # chars in a path name including nul */` -- константа, которая определяет максимальную длину имени файла вместе с каталогами в \*nix-ах

Comment: Что значит "формат файла"?

Comment: Ну (.txt, .cpp ).  + Вопрос, после повторного переименования , удаляются файлы ( если они уже переименованы). Каждый раз когда компилируешь -2 файла.От чего это так?

Comment: Я видел что вы это написали , но мне просто интересно почему такое явление?

Comment: 1) хотите переименовывать a.txt в 1.txt и b.cpp в 2.cpp? Все можно (было бы желание). Вы уж сразу в тексте вопроса напишите правила переименования. 2) В каталоге не может быть 2-х одинаковых имен (довольно очевидно, что в противном случае файлы будет очень неудобно искать -). Почему разработчики решили удалять, а не возвращать ошибку? **Интересный вопрос**, не знаю, но думаю в основе лежали какие-то свойства характера этих людей, к примеру, отсутствие занудства). Поэтому если переименовать `a` в `1`, а потом `b` в `1`, то старое содержимое `1` (изначально `a`) будет удалено.